# Umbraco 7.6.1 Upgrade Login Issue - 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7, http-status-code-400

After Upgrading from Umbraco 7.5.3 to 7.6.1 I have become unable to log in to the backoffice as an admin.

I have checked in the Users Database and userDisabled & userNoConsole are both 0,

My Username, UserLogin & UserEmail are all the same,

And I have a site running off the same database on 7.5.3 that I can log in to with the same credentials with no issue (so I can confirm my password is definitely correct!),

When I try and log in I get a 'Login failed for user xxx@xxx.com' message.

The Chrome error console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/PostLogin
```

Which when clicked on shows

```
)]}',
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

I have tried the UrlRewrite trick

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Redirect rule to force all URLs to lowercase -->
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/umbraco" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/install" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So I can log in using '/Umbraco' rather than '/umbraco'

I have updated client dependency to wipe any js cache, and cleared my browser history. I have also tried clearing App_data.

All front end of the site works perfectly, as far as I can tell

How can I log in to my back office in 7.6.1?!

Comment: Have you tried clearning the cookies?

Comment: @DZL I have tried clearing cookies on chrome(the browser used when trying the above), and using firefox, which has never accessed the site before.

Comment: What about clearing App_Data folder?

Comment: Even wiping the App_Data has no effect

Comment: Have you checked the log for any errors? /App_data/Logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Tristram does your site use Legacy encoding?

You may need to change your web.config back to using legacy encoding if this is so to do this update web.config useLegacyEncoding=true

From release notes: https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/761

**In web.config do NOT change useLegacyEncoding to false if it is currently set to true - changing the password encoding will cause you not being able to log in any more**

Comment: Thanks @TrtlBoy this was the solution to my problem, changed useLegacyEncoding to true, and I'm logging in no problem! many thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was seeing this after an upgrade from 7.5.1 to 7.6.5, flipping that flag did the trick.  Wish I would have found this sooner.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted answer doesn't work, hopefully this solution might help you fixing this problem;

I had the same problem recently and for my case the problem was [301 Url Tracker umbraco package.](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker/) As it is mentioned [in this answer](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/50407-Login-failed-for-user-in-Umbraco-7#comment-192033); 301 Url Tracker package was messing up paths for Umbraco Backoffice API methods and after deleting all the records in icUrlTracker table, all started working and I could finally login to umbraco backoffice using the old credentials that I had.

[image]